# Iterate collection from different threads

Tags: .net, multithreading

I have some threads, which adds,deletes,select from one List, and obviously, I'm getting Exception: InvalidOperationException, cause collection was changed due to another operation. So, i understand, that its bad design of my code, and etc.
Here goes the question:
what is the easyeist way from such situation, how can i improve situation without rewriting whole code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to use the `lock` construct, like this:

```
lock(myList)
{
    myList.Add(somevalue);
}
```

This will allow only 1 thread at a time to access the list. You'll need a `lock` anywhere that you're using the list to be safe.

Comment: hmmm, just a little explanaition of this mechanism?

Comment: This wraps the C# Monitor class, which allows only 1 thread at a time through that block of code. If two threads hit this statement at the same time, one is allowed through and the other waits. This way the list can only be accessed by a single thread at any given time, and you shouldn't get the InvalidOperationException.

Comment: oh, yes yes yes, thx, just didnt wake up. Ok, thanks man, think it will work!

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to insert, update, and delete concurrently, you can write your own implementation of `IList<T>` that aggregates a regular list and uses `lock(...)` to protect all read and write operations (like Contains, Add, etc).

Enumerating the list in safe manner is also possible, but would require that you make a copy of its contents rather than just returning an enumerator to the inner list.

You could also look at using the new concurrent collections in .NET 4.0. While there is no `ConcurrentList<T>` , you may be able to use `ConcurrentQueue<T>` instead.